# Jquery on specific image load

Tags: jquery

I know that `$(window).load` fires when all of the images on the page have loaded. I am looking to have something simular for when a specific image has been loaded to the page. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

E.g.

```
<img src="book.png" alt="Book" id="book" />


$('#book').load(function() {
  // Handler for .load() called.
});
```

**Update:**

If the image is already loaded by the time a load handler is specified, the load handler will not be triggered.  So it is best to specify the image source after setting the load handler.

```
<img id="book" />

...

$('#book').load(function() {
  alert('loaded') ;
});
$('#book').attr('src','book.png') ;
```

Comment: @NeXXeuS, the URL I gave has a section called "Caveats of the load event when used with images".  But this stuff (or at least the Javascript equivalent) has always worked for me.

Comment: @Thomas, you might have a race condition where the image is already loaded before you've specified the handler.  You can either try specifying the handler earlier (like in `$(document).ready()`), or set the image `src` attribute after setting the image `load` handler.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the load event to images as well.

```
$('#myimage').load(function() {
  console.debug('My image has loaded...');
});
```